# PluginInstall vs BundleInstall command in Vundle?

Tags: vim, plugin

On [the Vundle GitHub page](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) it says that one should use `PluginInstall` to install plugins, but when I search for Vundle on the web people often use `BundleInstall` instead. Both commands seems to be available. Is there a difference, and what should be used when?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Commands with the word `Plugin` should be preferred.

In past plugins used to be called "bundles", therefore all associated commands had "bundle" in the name. In the beginning of 2014 there was a global rename (see [this commit](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim/commit/0521de95eac09298c4e71b3662839612280c1ae9)). The old "bundle" commands were left only for compatibility reasons.